# Orbot browser Mobil device

Tags: orbot, android

What orbot browser is recommend for a type-c Android mobile device. 
Specifically Motorola's Moto z2 force model xt 1789-01.

Answer (score 0):

what is a *"type-c Android mobile device"*?

---

anyway... the browser to use with Tor resp. [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) on every android is [**Orfox**](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orfox/).

the [Tor Browser for Android](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#android) is still in alpha-phase and **not recommended** for now.